# Getting Average based on 2 conditions (columns and rows)

Tags: sql, oracle, average

My data is looking like this:

```
    PRODUCT DEPT DATE   PERCENTAGE
    1       A    JAN    2
    1       B    FEB    4
    1       A    MAR    1
    1       B    JAN    5
    1       A    FEB    3
    1       B    MAR    7
    1       A    JAN    3
    1       B    FEB    4
    1       A    MAR    2
    1       B    JAN    8
    1       A    FEB    9
    1       B    MAR    6
    ...    ...   ...    ...
```

With thousands of different products and dozens of departments.

The calculation I have to go through is:

1 - Sum the percentages as follow: by product, dept and date (so Product 1 / DEPT A / JAN => SUM(PERCENTAGE). For each PRODUCT, DEPT and DATE.
2 - When I have my sums, get the average of the 3 months for each product and dept (product 1 dept A: JAN / FEB / MAR, and so on)
3 - Get the max average (for each product, which dept has the highest average).

I have something which works but it's so long I am sure I can learn and make something better:

```
Select
Verylong_q.TFC,
Round(MAX(verylong_q.average),2) AS HIGHEST_AVERAGE
FROM

(
SELECT
Long_Q.TFC,
Long_Q.DEPT,
Long_Q.Percentage1,
Long_Q.Percentage2,
Long_Q.Percentage3,
((Percentage1 + Percentage2 + Percentage3)/3) AS Average
FROM
(
SELECT
t_Month1.TFC,
t_Month1.DEPT,
t_Month1.Percentage1,
t_Month2.Percentage2,
t_Month3.Percentage3
From
(
Select
pos.TFC,
mv.Dept AS Sector,
sum(pos.percentage) AS Percentage3
FROM
TBO_POS pos,
TBL_MV mv
Where
pos.IV_ID = mv.IV_ID
and Date = […]
and TFC in […]
group by pos.TFC, mv.Dept, pos.Date
order by 1 DESC ) t_Month1
LEFT JOIN
(
Select
pos.TFC,
mv.Dept AS Sector,
sum(pos.percentage) AS Percentage2
FROM
TBO_POS pos,
TBL_MV mv
Where
pos.IV_ID = mv.IV_ID
and Date = […]
and TFC in […]
group by pos.TFC, mv.Dept, pos.Date
order by 1 DESC ) t_Month2
On t_month1.DEPT = t_month2.DEPT and t_month1.TFC = t_month2.TFC
LEFT JOIN
(
Select
pos.TFC,
mv.Dept AS Sector,
sum(pos.percentage) AS Percentage3
FROM
TBO_POS pos,
TBL_MV mv
Where
pos.IV_ID = mv.IV_ID
and Date = […]
and TFC in […]
group by pos.TFC, mv.Dept, pos.Date
order by 1 DESC ) t_Month3
on t_month1.DEPT = t_month3.DEPT and t_month1.TFC = t_month3.TFC
) Long_Q
) VeryLong_Q
Group by verylong_q.TFC
```

How could I do this in a better way? Thanks!

Comment: What does that have to do with PL/SQL. Are you trying to indicate that you are using the Oracle DBMS?

Answer (score 3):

Isn't that simply:

1. Sum the percentages by product, dept and date in the innermost subquery
2. Get the average of the months for each product and dept in the next subquery
3. Get the max average for each product in the main query.

Query:

```
select product, max(avg_sum_percentage)
from
(
  select product, dept, avg(sum_percentage) as avg_sum_percentage
  from
  (
    select product, dept, date, sum(percentage) as sum_percentage
    from mytable
    group by product, dept, date
  ) per_product_dept_date
  group by product, dept
) per_product_dept
group by product;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you describer `lag()` seems like the appropriate method, along with aggregation and selection of the best:

```
select *
from (select product, dept, (sump_1 + sump_2 + sump_3) /3 as avg_max,
             row_number() over (partition by product order by (sump_1 + sump_2 + sump_3) /3 desc) as seqnum
      from (select product, dept, date, sum(percentage) as sump,
                   lag(sum(percentage)) over (partition by product, dept order by date) as sump_1,
                   lag(sum(percentage, 2)) over (partition by product, dept order by date) as sump_2
            from TBO_POS pos join
                 TBL_MV mv
                 on pos.IV_ID = mv.IV_ID
            where Date = […] and TFC in […]
            group by product, dept, date
           ) t
      ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This solution follows the description of the problem.  It produces one row for each month and product.  This version does not take into account missing values and other issues.  I *think* this is the logic you want, but without expected results the question might be ambiguous.